# Input gets messed up inside <details> tag

Tags: html, css, halfmoon

I am putting an input group inside a `<details>` tag. Outside, it works nicely, but inside, the input's height increases. Please note, I am using [Halfmoon](https://www.gethalfmoon.com) for my project. (Disclaimer: I built the project myself)

Anyway, here is the code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/halfmoonui/halfmoon@1.0.3/css/halfmoon.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="content">
  
  <!-- Input group outside -->
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">Shop</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter products">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <br />
  
  <details open>
    <summary>Click to open/close</summary>
    This is the details for the summary.
    <!-- Input group inside -->
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">Shop</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter products">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </details>
  
</div>
```

As you can see, the input group on the inside of the `<details>` has a messed up height which also affects the text before it. Exactly what am I doing wrong here? For reference, the input group code is taken from the docs, specifically this example: https://www.gethalfmoon.com/docs/input-group/#stacking-text-and-buttons.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: note that this seems to be a chrome bug, works fine on Firefox

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yep, this works perfectly on FireFox. Just noticed this now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `box-sizing: border-box` to `.input-group`

```css
.input-group {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/halfmoonui/halfmoon@1.0.3/css/halfmoon.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="content">
  
  <!-- Input group outside -->
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">Shop</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter products">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <br />
  
  <details open>
    <summary>Click to open/close</summary>
    This is the details for the summary.
    <!-- Input group inside -->
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">Shop</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter products">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </details>
  
</div>
```

Comment: This is very interesting. Why does the `box-sizing` need to be explicit here? Seems like the framework already sets everything to `border-box`. Thanks anyway, this solves the issue.